# What is exact reason for "Unfortunately, app has stopped"?

Tags: system-error

This error seldom occur for system apps but sometimes it occur while open an application that newly installed and that app doesn't start.
[image]
Question isn't about specific app or process but exact reason and possibilities of this error occurrence.

Comment: Usually such errors (including error message and stack trace) can bee seen on `adb logcat` (Android Debug Bridge logcat).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a software standpoint, there are many types of errors.

All errors should have the ability to be handled as to let the application remain running, but sometimes there are errors that are uncaught. The developer is responsible for catching the errors or handling things to not allow errors to occur. However, there are some things that a developer is not able to foresee, so they slip past.

These uncaught errors can crash the application. They can range from any number of things, such as database access, file reading, values not being properly checked, etc. The program ends up trying to do something it is not capable of doing, and simply crashes.

Comment: So these errors dosen't appear while testing an application?

Comment: @Swapnil Sometimes they do, but some errors might be specific to a phone that they were unable to test, or there was some variable, that when set to a specific value, throws the error and the developers did not think about that scenario.

Comment: Oh I see thank you @CodeMonkey for your invaluable time.

Answer (score 2):

As per the answer above, Uncought errors are a major cause but also corrupt cache can be another issue. Sometimes  after installing  rom while not resetting, even system apps can crash. Try clearing cache through recovery or doing a complete factory reset on some cases. 
On the case of app errors, they can only be solved programmatically. Contact the developer to let them  fix it.